# scrapy hub - exceptions.ImportError: No module named pymodm

Tags: mongodb, scrapy, scrapinghub, pymodm

I can run my scrapy locally without any issues, however, when i try to run job from scrapinghub i get the following error (connecting to mongo atlas cloud):

```
exceptions.ImportError: No module named pymodm
```

I import using:

```
import pymodm
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Please read the relevant Scrapinghub CLI client: [Deploying dependencies](https://shub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#deploying-dependencies)

Comment: pip install pymodm

Answer (score 6):

Create a file named `scrapinghub.yml` in your project's main folder with following contents.

```
projects:
  default: 111149
requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
```

Where `111149` is my proejct ID on scrapinghub.

Create another file named `requirements.txt` in same directory.

and put your required modules along with the version number you are using in that file like so,

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

**PS:** I was using MySQLDB module so I put that.

Comment: do you know what the setting about mongodb ? I have the same issue but still can't figure it out now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117975/dependency-error-while-trying-to-run-project-on-scrapy-cloud