# Dependency error while trying to run project on Scrapy Cloud

Tags: scrapinghub

I create a project with `scrapy` and using `pymongo` save my data to `mongodb`.

I have checked my pymongo version is 3.5.1

When i deploy my project to scrapinghub and run it.

It shows error on scrapinghub `exceptions.ImportError: No module named pymongo`

I have created requirements.txt and scrapinghub.yml.
[image]

[image]

Why it shows error `exceptions.ImportError: No module named pymongo` ?
[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the format of requirements.txt which did not work for me too.

Please try this format instead

```
projects:
  default: 111149
requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
```

Also generate a temporary requirements file by `pip freeze > temp_req.txt` and see how your pymongo module is written inside that file, copy exact same line and put that into `requirements.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  i have changed the format like yours, and type command `pip freeze > temp_req.txt` under my project. I can see `pymongo==3.5.1`.  I run my project again still get `exceptions.ImportError: No module named pymongo`  :(

Comment: Did you delete your old build and project egg folder before redeploying it

Comment: What do you mean project egg folder ? Do you mean requirements.txt and scrapinghub.yml files ?

Comment: The `project.egg-info` and `build` folders

Comment: Oh i see it , no i don't.  Should i delete it before deploying it again ?

Comment: I have deleted `project.egg-info` folder now. And when i deploy it again , i still get error `No module named pymongo`  :(  Its confused with me.